# How to authenticate to LDAP using Spring LDAP

Tags: spring, spring-ldap

I'm kind of newbie on Spring Boot and have a Jndi code that authenticates to an LDAP server just fine.  But now i want to migrate my code to Spring LDAP, but get [LDAP: error code 49 - 80090308: LdapErr: DSID-0C09044E, comment: AcceptSecurityContext error, data 52e, v2580] every time.

So my JNDI code looks something like this:

```
    public void connect(String userName, String pwd) throws NamingException, IllegalStateException {
    Hashtable<String, String> env = new Hashtable<String, String>();
    try {
        env.put(LdapContext.CONTROL_FACTORIES, "com.sun.jndi.ldap.ControlFactory");
        env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, userName+"@domain.net);
        env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, pwd);
        env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");
        env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL,  "ldap://server:389");
        env.put(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION, "simple"); 
        context = new InitialDirContext(env); 
    } finally {
        if (context !=null) {
            log.info("Authentication successfull");
            try {
                context.close();
                context = null;
            } catch(NamingException ne) {
                log.error(ne.getMessage());
                ne.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {
            throw new  IllegalStateException("Can't obtain LDAP context");
        }
    }
}
```

Very straightforward.

So far i have configured in my Spring boot application.properties file, the following:

```
spring.ldap.urls=Ldap://server:389
spring.ldap.embedded.credential.username=cn=ceadministrator
spring.ldap.embedded.credential.password=******
spring.ldap.embedded.base-dn=dc=domain,dc=net
```

Letting Spring Ldap manage the connection and initialization

Implemented this in order to search for some user:

```
    public List<User> getUser(String userName) throws NamingException, LDAPException {
    LdapQuery query = LdapQueryBuilder.query()
                        .searchScope(SearchScope.SUBTREE)
                        .timeLimit(3000)
                        .countLimit(10)
                        .attributes("cn")
                        .base(ldapConfig.getBase())
                        .where("objectClass").is("user")
                        .and("sAMAccountName").is(userName);
                        
    log.info("ldapTemplate: "+ldapTemplate);
    return ldapTemplate.search(query, new UserAttributesMapper());
}

private class UserAttributesMapper implements AttributesMapper<User> {
    @Override
    public User mapFromAttributes(Attributes attributes) throws NamingException {
        User user = new User();
        if (attributes == null) {
            log.warn("atttrs null");
            return user;
        }
        user.setFirstName((String) attributes.get("cn").get());
        Attribute sn = attributes.get("sAMAccountName");
        if (sn != null) {
            user.setUserName((String) sn.get());
        }
        return user;
    }
}
```

But it throws an AutheticationException:

```
javax.naming.AuthenticationException: [LDAP: error code 49 - 80090308: LdapErr: DSID-0C09044E, comment: AcceptSecurityContext error, data 52e, v2580
```

What am i missing/doing wrong?... Please help

Answer (score 0):

Well finally i got it.

I discovered that SpringBoot offers an embedded LDAP server, inserting the
"unboundid-ldapsdk" dependency into your pom.xml file.  This is no my desired scenario, because i already had a production environment LDAP server to connect to.

So i simply needed to configure the following properties in my application.properties file like this:

```
spring.ldap.urls=Ldap://192.17.1.4:389
spring.ldap.base=ou=Organization,OU=Some users unit,dc=depr,dc=net
spring.ldap.username=administrator
spring.ldap.password=SomePassword
```

Understanding that the "Spring.ldap.base" is the **base** where my searches are going to start and has nothing to do with my administrator credentials.